# ¿Existe alguna forma de obtener una contraseña encriptada?

Tags: php, mysqli, hash

Estoy intentando conectar una página web con un foro en phpbb3, tengo un botón con el cual intento añadir una cuenta al foro con los datos que tengo en mi base de datos de la página. El problema es que para la página utilizo `Whirlpool` y phpbb3 utiliza `MD5` (tengo entendido), y al momento de obtener la contraseña del usuario de mi base de datos, lo mucho que puedo obtener es la contraseña encriptada:

```
$getPassword = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT pass FROM table WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Esto arroja la siguiente cadena:

```
1b127b6acc1630e8fbae36a049755d8b1d6586631cf75ef5ec…07392d4d0d22fca44831ed7d8aaaa62c232946e7d09ce84e8
```

La forma más lógica que se me ha ocurrido es desencriptar esa cadena y luego que phpbb3 la encripte por si sólo, ¿existe una forma de obtener la cadena sin encriptar o de pasar esa contraseña a phpbb3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, no hay ninguna forma porque tus contraseñas no están *[encriptadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_(criptograf%C3%ADa))* sino *[hasheadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash_criptogr%C3%A1fica)*: por diseño, no es posible obtener el valor original (o al menos, no es razonable en términos de tiempo de computación) a partir de un hash. Precisamente por eso las funciones hash se usan para almacenar contraseñas: aunque un atacante logre hacerse con tu base de datos, no podrá descifrar las contraseñas de los usuarios (aunque en la práctica existen técnicas que funcionarían para contraseñas débiles, como los [ataques de diccionario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_diccionario)).

En estos casos la mejor opción es pedirle a todos los usuarios (por ejemplo enviándoles un email, o la siguiente vez que intenten iniciar sesión) que reseteen su contraseña, no sé si eso sería una opción viable en tu caso.

Más información al respecto en [esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948393/4574).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, creo que me iré por pedirle que ingrese una nueva contraseña.